# PK bring up multiple results but shows as the same PK number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a name of a "Segment" but when i put in the PK it brings up almost 1k results

The first query i need for the second query (note i am trying to get this to work in the first query but to help find out why its doing it i am doing it in two query)

```
DECLARE 
@vnuID int = 1212,
@StartDate datetime = '18/11/2013 00:00:00',
@EndDate datetime = '18/11/2013 11:59:59',
@Users int = 538

SELECT DISTINCT trID,
    CAST(trFinish - trStart AS TIME(2)) AS SegmentTime,
    CAST(CAST(@StartDate AS DATE) AS Varchar(50)) + ' - ' + CAST(CAST(@EndDate AS DATE) AS Varchar(50)) AS DateRage
    --,segName
FROM 
    tblTrace
    INNER JOIN tblUsers ON usrID = tr_usrID
    INNER JOIN VS.dbo.tblSegments ON seg_vnuID = tr_vnuID
WHERE 
    (tblTrace.trFinish IS NOT NULL)
    AND (tblTrace.trObjectType LIKE 'Segment%') 
    AND (tblTrace.tr_vnuID = @vnuID) 
    AND (tblTrace.trStart BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
    AND (tblUsers.usrEmail NOT LIKE '%@test%')
    AND usrID IN (@Users)
GROUP BY trID, trFinish, trStart--, segName
```

This is to find the segment name but brings up many results

```
SELECT trID, segName 
FROM VS.dbo.tblSegments
    INNER JOIN tblTrace ON tr_vnuID = seg_vnuID
WHERE trID = 224663
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple rows in the `VS.dbo.tblSegments` table which have the same `seg_vnuID` as the `tr_vnuID` on the specified `tblTrace` row.